# Adding Listeners to a DefaultTableModel

Tags: java, swing, swingworker, defaulttablemodel, listselectionlistener

I use a SwingWorker to change a DefaultTableModel according to changes in a database. My question is:  is it safe to add a ListSelectionListener and a TableModelListener to the DefaultTableModel in doInBackground(), or do they have to be added in done()?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any action that modifies any GUI component in any way *should* be performed on the EDT. You should be adding the listeners in `done`.

Comment: +1 seems [according to Swing Worker docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#publish(V...)) `DefaultTableModel` and all Swing components can also be modified/added within `process(..)` without need of `SwingUtilities.invokeXXX` block.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp The [`process`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process(java.util.List)) method is performed on the EDT, so it is perfectly fine to add the listeners there as well.